# Is MVC applicable to JavaScript web applications?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, web

I am trying to understand if `MVC` (as it works in Java desktop applications, for example) is applicable to JavaScript web applications.

By `MVC` I mean the following :

- *Model* is data that represent the application state. It is not aware of the page DOM.
- *View* is the DOM tree and functions, which listen to the Model changes and update the DOM
- *Controller* listens to user gestures (e.g. "button pressed"), calls the server, and updates the *Model* rather than *View*.

I looked through few JavaScript applications and saw something different. They do not have clear distinction between *Model* and *View*. That is, the application state is scattered over the DOM tree and *Controller* (e.g. ajax callbacks) updates the *View* (DOM tree) directly.

Now I wonder if the `MVC` as described above is really applicable to JavaScript applications running in the browser. What do you think?

Comment: it's "JavaScript", with a single word :)

Comment: MVC is a pattern and can be applied anywhere there's a way to separate the concerns, including on the client side. A trivial search for "javascript mvc" probably would have answered this question far more completely.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks. Do you have any experience with MVC in JavaScript ? For what kind of applications would you recommend it ?

Comment: Any kind, although for small apps, or pages with very light client-side requirements, it's probably not worth it unless the team is already using a framework. The more the client side needs to do, the more value molding the app into a framework brings. Like anything else, "it depends".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC with JavaScript exists and is already possible. There are tons of library out there. I give you some ressource to dig in:

- http://addyosmani.com/toolsforjqueryapparchitecture/
- http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/
- https://gist.github.com/441889
- http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/mvc-architecture-for-javascript-applications
- http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-apps-spinejs/

Addy Osmani blog contains a lot of informations about JavaScript design patterns, and especifically about MVC, you should have a look there http://addyosmani.com/blog/. He also has written a book about design patterns in Javascript http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, due to it's dynamic nature, these patterns vary, depending on the programmer that builds them and the applications that are built on it. And MVC is just one in [a whole bunch of patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use MVC for JavaScript applications, and [there is no shortage of frameworks to help](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=19&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+mvc+frameworks).

There are plenty of applications that don't though (in part because JavaScript hasn't been widely considered a "serious" language until recently, so such development practises are new to large parts of the JS community).